# Is there a way to run an async function in dask client?

Tags: asynchronous, dask

Is there some way of wrapping or submitting jobs like this?

```
async def f(x):
    return x


fut = client.submit(f, 1)
```

TypeError: can't pickle coroutine objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions submitted with the `.submit` API are run in a thread pool that is separate from the main worker's event loop thread.  This thread pool is not appropriate for running asynchronous functions.

However, you can submit an async function to run on the worker's main event loop using the `client.run` method.

```
client.run(f, 1)
```

However, this runs `f` on *all* workers.  If you want to select a single worker then you might do something like this

```
workers = list(client.scheduler_info()["workers"])
client.run(f, 1, workers=[workers[0]])
```